# How to Implement a Smart Chunking Bootstrap Carousel with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, carousel, owl-carousel, slick.js

I want a carousel slider on my website.I am using ng-repeat to get its data from my server.here is my code :

```
<div id="dynamiccontentcarousel" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#dynamiccontentcarousel" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in ExpImage| groupBy: 'index'" data-ng-class="{active : $first}" data-slide-to="{{$index}}"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div  data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in ExpImage| groupBy: 'index'">
            <div ng-repeat="img in value" data-ng-class="{active : $first}">
                <img data-ng-src="image/{{img.img}}" style="width: 300px; height: 150px">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my js :

```
 for(var i = 0; i < $scope.exp_all_goods.length; i++)
                {
                    $scope.ExpImage.push({img:$scope.exp_all_goods[i].img, index: Math.floor(i / 4)});

                }
```

I am using bootstrap 4 carousel and angular.filter for group by filter in my ng-repeat.my data :
$scope.exp_all_goods =[ {img: "310.jpg"}

,
{img: "311.jpg"}

,
{img: "312.jpg"}

,
{img: "313.jpg", index: 0}]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the carousels have issues with ng-repeat. We have certain work-around for slick carousel http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Include condition checking for last element in the iterator and let the directive get triggered only after that. 'if ( scope.$last )' in below mentioned code does the same for you.

```
function slickCarouselEL(smoothScroll) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      if ( scope.$last ) {
        $(element.parent()).slick({
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          autoplay: true,
          dots: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 4000,
          responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 400,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                dots: false
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 900,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                dots: false
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1200,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
              }
            }
          ]
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-card class="image-container" flex="100">
     <div class="img-carousel" ng-if="dataLoaded">
         <div class="slick-carousel" ng-repeat="img in imageList" ng-if="dataLoaded" init-onload="false" data="dataLoaded" slick-carousel-el>
                <div class="item">
                    <md-card class="img">
                         <img src="{{img}}">
                    </md-card>
                </div>
          </div>
     </div>   
</md-card>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.can I see the html to see how to use this directive?i have written one .but it is not considered as a directive to angular.

Comment: can you help me please?

Comment: please include the plunker, would help knowing the exact issue.

Comment: i have edited the code.can you help me with this one ?